# Is there an official list of supported countries for iAd?

Tags: iphone, iad

Where can I find it? Or can anyone please update what's the countries that are currently has iAd coverage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

Seems like my original answer was a bit misleading. The list on https://iad.apple.com shows which countries there have been sent iAd *requests* from. The column labeled *Impressions* shows which countries that have actually received iAds (and where iAds are supported).

So the actual list of supported countries is a lot smaller. **USA, UK, France, Germany, Italy, Spain and Japan** are supported.

It might be worth to mention that I have seen stats showing that other countries have received iAds, e.g. Norway, but only with a fill rate of less than 1%. I'm a bit curious on how this may happen, so if anyone know why, please explain.

---

**Original post: (NB! The following is not correct. I'll leave it as it is for reference.)**

I could not find any **complete** official list, but I know the ads are served in at least the following 18 countries. There might be other countries that I don't know of too, where my app has not served any ads yet. I found this list by logging in to https://iad.apple.com.

First page:

[image: First 15 countries]

Second page:

[image]

Comment: I think this is wrong. We don't get iAds in Greece. Look the post by 
ileff. I think is more accurate.

Comment: @Gik, Greece is not listed as one one the countries in the updated answer. I listed it in my first edit of the answer, but not anymore. It should be clear enough as it is now.

Comment: Nice. And now that I have your attention ;-) let me ask you this: Is there a way to "find" programmatically if the user is in a country that serves ads or not? bannerViewDidLoadAd will not tell you, because it runs even with the Apple-generic ad.

Answer (score 4):

That list was countries his app was used in and sent in requests for ads.

There is a shorter list of countries that actually serve ads:

USA, UK, France, Germany, Spain, Italy, Japan, Canada, Australia, New Zealand, and Mexico

Comment: which means unless you are targeting another country which is NOT listed above, you should use another ad portal (etc. admob)

Answer (score 4):

November 2014 Update: There are now over a hundred supported countries. The list is now accessible here: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203102

Even if a country listed as supported, there is no guarantee of any inventory to show, especially for newly added countries.

---

The iAd Workbench in Apple Developer Support maintains a list under the 'Availability' heading:

**https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/iad-workbench/**

As at October 2014, there are 25 countries listed as supported:

- Australia
- Austria
- Belgium
- Canada
- Denmark
- Finland
- France
- Germany
- Ireland
- Italy
- Hong Kong
- Japan
- Luxembourg
- Mexico
- Netherlands
- New Zealand
- Norway
- Poland
- Russia
- Spain
- Sweden
- Switzerland
- Taiwan
- United States
- United Kingdom

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. Apple recently expanded support to over a hundred countries, but Hungary isn’t one of them (at least, not yet).

Comment: So I will not able to see any ads when using my own released App here in Hunagary at all

Answer (score 1):

Per iTunes Connect:

> The iAd Network has recently launched in Canada, Australia, and New
>   Zealand. Ads are now available in apps in the U.S., Canada, Australia,
>   New Zealand, Japan, France, Germany, Italy, Spain, and the U.K App
>   Stores. Be sure to configure your apps to serve ads in only these
>   countries.

Comment: Mexico has now been added as well.  Per Apple: "iAd campaigns currently run in the U.S, Canada, Mexico, U.K., France, Germany, Italy, Spain, Australia, New Zealand, and Japan."

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official list by logging into iTunes Connect and navigating to FAQ > iAd App Network.

The list of countries supported by iAd can be found in the answer for "What is the difference between the iAd Fill Rate and the Fill Rate?". As of June 2014, the answer states:

> The iAd Fill Rate adjusts the number of total ad requests to reflect
>   only those countries supported by the iAd App Network. **These countries
>   include Australia, Canada, France, Germany, Hong Kong, Ireland, Italy,
>   Japan, Mexico, New Zealand, Spain, Taiwan, the United Kingdom and the
>   United States.**