# iAd does not appear on my app on the AppStore

Tags: ios, iad

I have summited app with iAd integrated, which can be downloaded from AppStore.
The problem is that iAd is working in the development phase, but is not when the app is available in the App Store.

I have iAd contracts in effect in 'Agreements, Tax, and Banking' menu from iTunes Connect, but not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

The AppStore takes some days to check your app and then they decide if your app is elegible for iAds, if they approve it (most likely), the iAds will automatically appear on your app and the details on you iAd Network.

By experience I can tell you that the process may take from one day to a couple of weeks.

If you feel they are taking to long to activate them, you can always send an email to Apple and they will solve it for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

The two most likely reasons are:

1. Your app is still being reviewed for iAd (this runs separately from the App Store review).

   You can check this by going to http://iad.apple.com using your iTunes Connect login. See if your app’s Ad Status is “Live Ads”, and also check the Messages tab in case there’s anything interesting there.
2. There are no ads being served (it could be you are in a country without iAd support, or limited ad inventory).

   There is a list of supported countries in this [StackOverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25291783/1048060). If this is the case, you’ll need to find someone in a supported country to check this for you. Test ads will always work in development, regardless of your country.